# Can cookie be set against top level domain like .com

Tags: http, cookies, setcookie

I have a question related to [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) - what would happen if I set the domain while setting cookie as .com? Would the cookie be available to all .com websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-configured user-agents should reject such cookies, as explained in [RFC 6265 section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3):

> 5. If the user agent is configured to reject "public suffixes" and the domain-attribute is a public suffix:
>
> - If the domain-attribute is identical to the canonicalized request-host:
>
>   - Let the domain-attribute be the empty string.
> - Otherwise:
>
>   - Ignore the cookie entirely and abort these steps.
>
> NOTE: A "public suffix" is a domain that is controlled by a
> public registry, such as "com", "co.uk", and "pvt.k12.wy.us".
> This step is essential for preventing attacker.com from
> disrupting the integrity of example.com by setting a cookie
> with a Domain attribute of "com".  Unfortunately, the set of
> public suffixes (also known as "registry controlled domains")
> changes over time.  If feasible, user agents SHOULD use an
> up-to-date public suffix list, such as the one maintained by
> the Mozilla project at http://publicsuffix.org/.

Comment: What does it mean by `Let the domain-attribute be the empty string.` ? If domain attribute is empty, then what happens ?